# Access Version Maintenance

Tags: ms-access

I have an access database (access 2010) where the data is being entered everyday by some people through forms. I am also working on it to develop new forms and new queries. The problem is that I am developing a form and by the time I put it on the current version of database, more data is being entered and so consistency is being lost. Is there a way in which I can deal with this problem.

Comment: Erm, missing something here. In what way does more data make your form inconsistant?

Answer (score 1):

An Access database should always be split into a back-end for data and a front-end for forms and so forth. The back-end tables are then linked to the front-end. ( [How to split db](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/split-an-access-database-HA010342026.aspx), [Reasons to split db](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10things/10-reasons-to-split-an-access-database/1119) )

Each user gets a copy of the front-end and the back-end resides on a computer that all have access to.

Develop on a copy of the front-end and when you are finished, relink the tables and distribute the new version to each user ( [Front-end maintenance](http://autofeupdater.com/) ).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please explain me how this can be done or point me to resources that has the related information.

Comment: I included three link references in my reply, did you see them?

Comment: You have some great links and explain as to how this works. 

I explain the concept of splitting here:
http://www.kallal.ca/Articles/split/index.htm

Often an explain of "why" one does this as opposed to just being told to split often helps one grasp this approach to software development. Article here

Comment: @Remou: Thank you. Yes, I have seen the links and they indeed have lot of useful information.